# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b64encode' python 3.9 base64 encoding string fail

Tags: python, base64

```
import base64


def base64(text):
    newText = base64.b64encode(text.encode())
    return newText
```

This is function the main calls with input, gets string and returns the encoded string. I keep on getting the following error-

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b64encode'
```

I have tried string or bytes as parameter but the error stays the same.

Comment: Was that supposed to be `import base64` (no space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have imported `base64` but then created your own function with the same name `base64`. That means the references to `base64` after your definition of the function (including inside of it) will be to **your function** and not to the module.

That's what the error is refering to a function `base64` which does not have the attribute you are referencing `b64encode`.

In order to fix this, all you have to do is change the name of your function to something else, for example - `my_base64` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

`import base64` imports the module and binds it to the module variable "base64". The following `def base64(...):` compiles a function object and then rebinds the module variable "base64". By the time you use it, its now a function. The solution is to rename your function, perhaps

```
def my_encoder(text):
    ...
```